# Add a data connection to TFS version control

Tags: sql, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-express

I am working on a visual studio web project in express 2013.

I also created a `(localdb)\v11.0` data connection and added a bunch of tables and stored procedures.

My question is how can I check in this data to TFS version control?

The website project I am working on is already in TFS. I looked around and I see that I can add a sql project and then create tables and procedures which can be checked in.

Do I need to create an SQL database project and check it in?

If yes, is there an easy way to move the existing tables and procedures to the project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Database project using the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

This project helps you in bringing tables, views, stored procedures and permissions under version control. After creating a new, empty database project you can choose to import the schema from an existing database. After importing the project you can make your changes directly in Visual Studio in the Database project and then update your localdb or the other way around.

[[image: The context menu lets you import an existing database[1]]

Importing an existing schema is only possible when your Database project is empty. After an initial import, you need to use Schema Compare to import further changes from your database into your project.